# Unable to install ansible on red hat 7

Tags: ansible

Unable to install ansible. Error nothing to do package ansible not available . Red hat 7

Performed yum upadte 
Installed epel package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the docs is always a good first step.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_installation.html

> We’ve changed how the Ansible community packages are distributed. For users of RHEL/CentOS/Scientific Linux version 7, the Ansible community RPM package will transition from the EPEL repository to the Extras channel. There will be no change for version 6 of RHEL/CentOS/Scientific Linux since Extras is not a part of version 6.

Comment: Just to add to that, you're going to want to run this command to enable the `extras` repo: `subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms`

Comment: still getting the error :[root@localhost ~]# rpm -Uvh ./rpm-build/ansible-*.noarch.rpm
error: File not found by glob: ./rpm-build/ansible-*.noarch.rpm

Comment: @Adityaraj Why are you building the RPM yourself instead of turning on `extras`? Unless you intend to use the self-built RPM elsewhere, just enable the right repo, or barring that, [install from source](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_installation.html#running-from-source).